# How can one leverage the Salesforce UI API to create dynamic Lightning components?

Tags: rest-api, ui

Having reviewed the Salesforce UI API, I know it is possible to create custom UIs based on Salesforce meta-data.

The use cases that have been shown are front end apps, usually built with React or a similar framework.

However, can one leverage the Salesforce UI API to also enhance existing Lightning components?

For example, let's say that I have overriden the Account 'New' button to display a custom Lightning component. Let's also say that the Account has multiple record types which have different fields and therefore different page layouts. Using the Salesforce UI API, is it possible to use the parsed in record type Id from the Lightning component initiated by the 'New' override to then query the Salesforce meta-data to dynamically display the different fields?

I have been trying to achieve this and I am calling the Salesforce UI API from my developer org but I don't understand how I could then deserialize the JSON response, send it to the Lightning component to then dynamically display the fields on the fly. It seems possible in theory but I haven't see any examples of how to achieve this from the blogosphere.